# Is specifying the listening HTTP port via UseUrls the correct way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I have successfully deployed an asp.net core mvc to windows iot core on my raspberry pi 3.

I am not sure whether specifying the listening HTTP port via invoking `UseUrls` as shown in the following snippet is the correct way.

```
namespace winiotrasp
{
    public class Program
    {
        // ... others ...

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:80")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

## Questions

Is specifying the listening HTTP port via `UseUrls` the correct way?

Note that If I don't specify as shown above, the default setting is `http://localhost:5000` which makes the web server inaccessible from other devices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is the correct way.The **UseUrls** method is for indicates the IP addresses or host addresses with ports and protocols that the server should listen on for requests. Please reference [Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x). If you don't specify the the IP addresses or host addresses with ports, you can use cmdlet *$env:ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:5000"* to change the default setting, then run the web server and it will be inaccessible from other devices.